# Multiple Markers with ItemisedOverlay Android

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

In my application i have multiple latitude and longitude from my web service. At this point in time, i am able to display only one coordinate on goole map using the code below.

```
public class CustomMap extends MapActivity {

    MapView mapView;
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    Drawable drawable;
    Drawable drawable2;
    CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlay2;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gmap);
        //setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.main_ou, null));

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        // second overlay
        drawable2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red);
        itemizedOverlay2 = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable2, mapView);
        GeoPoint point3 =  new GeoPoint((int)(-10.224609*1E6),(int)(17.506044*1E6));
        CustomOverlayItem overlayItem3 = new CustomOverlayItem(point3, "Title", 
        "Cliquez here", null);

        itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(overlayItem3);
        //itemizedOverlay2.onTap(0);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);

        final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.animateTo(point3);
        mc.setZoom(16);

    }


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }




}
```

Now, i want to set latitude and longitude  on the map dynamically using arrays. I am using  ArrayList val; to get and set data. Can someone give me a hint on how to make the class dynamic.

**NEW UPDATE THE CODE BELOW DISPLAYS ONLY ONE MARKER BUT I WANT ALL MARKERS TO APPEAR**

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {

     private MapController mapControll;
     private GeoPoint geoPoint=null;
     private MapView mapview;
     private MyItemizedOverlay userPicOverlay;
     private MyItemizedOverlay nearPicOverlay;
     private Drawable userPic,atmPic;
     private CustomOverlayItem nearatms[] = new CustomOverlayItem[50];
     public static Context context;

     double latitude,longitude;



    ArrayList<Article> mArticles;
    CustomOverlayItem overlayItem3 ;
    public ArrayList<Article> articles;
    public static ArrayList<Article> article;

    EditText search;
    DBHelper helper;
    GeoPoint point;

    MapView mapView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aproximite);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_box);

        helper = DBHelper.getInstance(this);

        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1E6),(int)(longitude * 1E6));          
        mapview = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapControll= mapview.getController();
        mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapview.setStreetView(true);
        mapControll.setZoom(16);
        mapControll.animateTo(geoPoint);

        userPic = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boutton_log);
        userPicOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(userPic);
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "I'm Here!!!", null);
        userPicOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
        mapview.getOverlays().add(userPicOverlay);


        atmPic = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boutton_log);
        nearPicOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(atmPic);


        new GetLocationTask().execute();

    }




private class GetLocationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            mArticles = helper.getArticlesList();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {            

          try {

                for (int i = 0; i < mArticles.size(); i++) {


                    point =  new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(mArticles.get(i).getLatitude())*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(mArticles.get(i).getLongitude())*1E6));
                    nearatms[i] = new CustomOverlayItem(point ,"title", 
                    "click here", null);

                    nearPicOverlay.addOverlay(nearatms[i]);
                }
                mapview.getOverlays().add(nearPicOverlay);
                //Added symbols will be displayed when map is redrawn so force redraw now
                mapview.postInvalidate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
     }





@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

MyItemizedOverlay.class

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> myOverlays ;

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        myOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        populate();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay){
        myOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return myOverlays.get(i);
    }

    // Removes overlay item i
    public void removeItem(int i){
        myOverlays.remove(i);
        populate();
    }

    // Returns present number of items in list
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return myOverlays.size();
    }


    public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem) {
        myOverlays.add(overlayItem);
        populate();
    }


    public void addOverlayItem(int lat, int lon, String title) {
        try {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title, null);
            addOverlayItem(overlayItem);    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String title = myOverlays.get(index).getTitle();
        System.out.println(index);
        return super.onTap(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have started now? if yes, please switch over to Google map v2.

Comment: i don't know google map version i am using https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this way..

for google map v1 --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9630396/1168654

for Google MAP v2 check below code

call this method

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arraylist.size();i++){
    addMarker(mapview,arraylistLat.get(i),arraylistLong.get(i),title.get(i),arraysnippet.get(i));
}
```

---

```
private void addMarker(GoogleMap map, double lat, double lon,
            String string, String string2) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                .title(string).snippet(string2));
    }
```

Comment: i want to adapt it based on my code below because i have other data to add in the infowindow

Comment: Dude check update i tried it but only one marker get displayed and it doesn't display my infowindow on tap now

Comment: How to set onclick listener for all the generated markers in mapsv2 instead of title and snipet, I.e i wanna take it to another activity with some id values passing to that activity from clicked marker. How can i do it.

Comment: @JaiKumar: check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_click_events and this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_window_click_events

Comment: @Christina: your code is corrct. just try to add static marker (with diffrent location).and check its show you multiple or nor??. i thing there is problem with your array list.

Comment: Every latitude and longitude gets printed from the array list