# Google Maps Android API v2 Show marker on zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

How can show markers on specific zoom level using Google Maps Android API v2? I have more than 1000 Markers, so it's not good idea to show all on start.

Here is simple example:

#

// latitude and longitude

```
double latitude = 40.738933;

double longitude = -74.001366;
```

// create marker

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");
```

// adding marker

```
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

#

Thank you for help

Comment: Go through this https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Comment: Bro, there are thousands of duplicate questions on this topic on this site. Please search before posting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding multiple marker on google map in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295203/adding-multiple-marker-on-google-map-in-android)

Comment: try to implements OnCameraChangeListener

Answer (score 9, accepted):

put below code

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
```

here Move the camera instantly to marker with a zoom of 15. if you wanna change zoom level you can change.